# different types of edges in graphx

Tags: inheritance, apache-spark, spark-graphx

How can I add different types of edges in the same graphX graph. For instance and edge between node A and node B may have String attribute and an edge between node X and node Y may have (Int, Int) attr.

Is there a way to implement edge inheritance in graphX? 
Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

The vertex and edge types of a graph are specified using the [`VD` and `ED`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b2f24f94591082d3ff82bd3db1760b14603b38aa/graphx/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/graphx/Graph.scala#L41) type parameters on `Graph`. You can store different types of edge data on different edges as long as they share a common superclass. To do that, pass the common superclass as the `ED` type parameter when you construct the graph.

In your example, a common supertype of `String` and `(Int, Int)` is `Any`. You can construct a graph with edge attributes of both types like this:

```scala
val edges = List[Edge[Any]](
  Edge(1, 2, "foo"),
  Edge(3, 4, (123, 456)))

Graph.fromEdges(sc.parallelize(edges), 1)
```

Comment: further on this, if I have to use groupEdges on the same graph, how can that be done?

Comment: If I have a user defined edge attribute (say MySuperEdgeType) which can be subclassed into diff edgeTypes, then how would the grouping of Edges take place?

trait MySuperEdge {
    def edgeType : String
}

case class SubEdge1( edType: String, totalCnt :Int) extends MySuperEdge{
    def edgeType : String = { return edType }
    def edgeAttrValue : Int = { return totalCnt }
  }

  case class SubEdge2( edType: String, sales :Int, profit: Int, ) extends MySuperEdge{
    def edgeType :String = {return edType }
    def val1 :Int = {return sales}
    def val2 :Int ={return profit}
  }

Comment: val baseGraph = Graph(nodes, edgeRDD)
where edgeRDD is  RDD of  Edge[MySuperEdge]

In this case, after graph creation, how would I groupEdges?